# German order in English numbers? (Can I say 'five and forty' for 'forty-five'?)

Tags: numbers, german

In Tolkien's Lord of the Rings Gandalf says:

> **Five-and-forty** leagues as the crow flies we have come, though many long miles further our feet have walked.

What is *five-and-forty*? Is it really the same thing as German *fünfundvierzig*? Can I use it for any other number or is it just for *forty five*? And where and when this form will be appropriate?

Comment: That form is intentionally old-fashioned aiming for quaintness. It's not how speakers talk on the street.  It would fly in an historical novel, or a fantasy set in the past, or coming from the mouth of a fire-and-brimstone preacher perhaps, who spends a lot of time with the King James version of the bible.

Comment: Of course it is, the question is can I say “two and forty” for quaintness? ;)

Comment: It's only appropriate if you's as old as Gandalf.

Comment: @Vadim: Thou mayest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say numbers this way if you wish.

It is considered old-fashioned, even archaic to say numbers this way in English.  It does persist, often for more poetic uses.  Children (British ones at least) are still taught the nursery rhyme *Five and Twenty Blackbirds, baked in a pie*

This format was much more common fifty or so years ago.  That would put it more into Tolkein's time.

My Grandmother and her siblings all spoke numbers this way - not just *five and ...* but any number.  They were Irish, but I can't vouch for if the construction was more prevalent in Ireland than elsewhere.

Comment: +1 except that saying "the format was much more common fifty or so years ago"  can make it seem to the non-native learner  that fifty years ago  everyone  was going around saying *five and forty*, which is clearly not the case.  For instance Tolkien did not use it because it was more common in his day (it wasn't, outside of the Ireland you speak of); he used it to adopt a different manner for Gandalf to speak (perhaps in a more "Germanic" or Old-English manner, as opposed to a modern, or even Anglo-Norman  manner).

Comment: I don't mean everyone was saying it then.  Just noticeably more people than do now.  And, yes, I expect Tolkein was playing up the antiquity for literary effect.

Comment: "Four score and seven years ago..." - Abraham Lincoln, the Gettysburg Address.  It definitely sounds more poetic to a native U.S. speaker - but it's also easily understood, and not unheard of.